# clang-tidy duplicate errors when invoked by CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, clang-tidy

I have a problem with `clang-tidy`. Basically, it analyzes each of my project files, but for the headers that are included in more than one `.cpp` file, it prints redundant errors.

The problem is, Visual Studio Code has its `PROBLEMS` tab, which picks every single one of them, so for a file `definitions.hpp` which is included in 3 separate `.cpp` files I end up with something like this:

[image]

The console output is:

```
[build] [3/4  25% :: 14.699] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\solver.dir\src\definitions.cpp.obj
[build] [...]\build\..\src/definitions.hpp:1:9: warning: header guard does not follow preferred style [llvm-header-guard]
[build] #ifndef DEFINITIONS_HPP
[build]         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[...]
[build] [3/4  50% :: 16.138] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\solver.dir\src\genetic_algorithm.cpp.obj
[build] [...]\build\..\src/definitions.hpp:1:9: warning: header guard does not follow preferred style [llvm-header-guard]
[build] #ifndef DEFINITIONS_HPP
[build]         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[...]
[build] [3/4  75% :: 17.362] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\solver.dir\src\main.cpp.obj
[build] [...]\build\..\src/definitions.hpp:1:9: warning: header guard does not follow preferred style [llvm-header-guard]
[build] #ifndef DEFINITIONS_HPP
[build]         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

So, is there a way to prevent something like this? I mean it doubles of triples my error list.

@Edit

So this is my `clang-tidy`-relevant part of `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
if(CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_GREATER 3.6)
    option(CLANG_TIDY_FIX "Perform fixes for Clang-Tidy" OFF)
    find_program(
        CLANG_TIDY_EXE
        NAMES "clang-tidy"
        DOC "Path to clang-tidy executable"
    )

    if(CLANG_TIDY_EXE)
        if(CLANG_TIDY_FIX)
            set(CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY "${CLANG_TIDY_EXE}" "-fix")
        else()
            message("SETTING UP CLANG TIDY")
            set(CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY "${CLANG_TIDY_EXE}")
        endif()
    endif()
endif()
```

And this is my `.clang-tidy` file:

```
---
Checks:          '*'
HeaderFilterRegex: '.*'
AnalyzeTemporaryDtors: false
FormatStyle:     none
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a problem of how Visual Studio Code implements its support for clang-tidy.

Clang-tidy itself supplies [run-clang-tidy.py](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang-tools-extra/blob/master/clang-tidy/tool/run-clang-tidy.py) script file that runs clang-tidy over all files in a compilation database. It also prevents applying fixes multiple times in the same places of code.

Your options are:

- Fix the code so the warnings are not issued
- Use `//NOLINT` or `//NOLINTNEXTLINE` to suppress those warnings

EDIT:
After the discussion this looks to me like a problem of how clang-tidy is invoked by cmake - it runs separately on each target and clang-tidy has no way to know it reported some error before. You should only use CMake to generate `compile_commands.json` and then run clang-tidy via [run-clang-tidy.py](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang-tools-extra/blob/master/clang-tidy/tool/run-clang-tidy.py).

[This article](https://sarcasm.github.io/notes/dev/clang-tidy.html) seems to confirm my suspicion about clang-tidy integration with CMake.

Comment: The problem is, I want them. Isn't there a way to force clang-tidy to check if the error for a particular header was printed out before and if so, not print the error again? The I guess vscode would work to fine, the problem is it occurs 3 times in terminal

Comment: I think this is a problem of invoking clang-tidy by the VS Code Clang-tidy Linter (I assume that is what you're using) so you can submit this as an error report on their github.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I am invoking it in my build, in `CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: Ok then, this might be a problem of how you are invoking it, you should add that info to your question.

Comment: I've added my CMake clang-tidy configuration

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly