# How to avoid duplicate clang-tidy warnings coming from the same header?

Tags: c++, duplicates, clang-tidy

## Description

Recently I started using clang-tidy in a C++ project and I encountered an annoying problem. When a header contains error and is included in many .cpp files the error is reported multiple times by clang-tidy. Obviously the error is found in different .cpp files, but in fact the error is inside the header and I would like to see just one error message. Is it possible and how could it be done?

BTW: I am aware that a similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55822272/clang-tidy-duplicate-errors-when-invoked-by-cmake). However, the answer is not correct and the problem is not in invoking clang-tidy as a CMake target.

## How to reproduce the problem

It is quite easy to reproduce the problem, however it requires some boilerplate code. I am using `clang-tidy-12` but I am quite sure that this problem is still up-to-date in version 13 or 14. Consider these files in a single directory:

```cpp
// A.hpp
#pragma once

void foo(const int);
```

```cpp
// A.cpp
#include "A.hpp"

void foo(const int) {}
```

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include "A.hpp"

int main() {
    foo(2);
}
```

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

project(clang-tidy-test)

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp A.cpp)
```

Now just build the project:

```sh
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build .
```

Run clang-tidy inside the build dir:
`run-clang-tidy-12 -header-filter=.* -checks=-*,readability-avoid-const-params-in-decls`.

You can see that the same warning in file `A.hpp:3:10` is displayed twice.

Comment: Do you have control over the header file, or are you "stuck with it"?

Comment: I am in control of the header, it is part of the project I am working on, not an external dep.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to do it as clang-tidy is invoked in each translation unit. At least for `run-clang-tidy`.

Comment: So I guess I would have to use some kind of a script to filter out the duplicate output myself?